# Is there a way to tell when you first played a game on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Is there any way to see when I first played a game? I know the activity log will show "First Played" but after 10 days, it'll show how long you've played a game. Is there a way to see when you first played a game AFTER the 10 days? If not, is it possible to at least see when you installed a game on your Switch?

I installed the Nintendo Parental app on my phone but it only shows stats for games after I installed it, not before. I'm looking for a way to see when I first played or installed a game before having the app.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think it's possible, never found that option anywhere.

Switch lacks several nice features Nintendo 3DS and Nintendo WiiU used to have, one of them is [Activity Log](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Hardware/Nintendo-3DS-Family/Instant-Software/Activity-Log/Activity-Log-115580.html).